# New line being printed as "\n" instead of actual new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print a simple game board.

```
places = [" "] * 9
board = (places[8] + "|" + places[7] + "|" + places[6] + "\n",
         places[5] + "|" + places[4] + "|" + places[3] + "\n",
         places[2] + "|" + places[1] + "|" + places[0] + "\n")
print(board)
```

But instead of a board I get this:

```
(' | | \n', ' | | \n', ' | | \n')
```

I want to print it without the parentheses and with new lines instead of \n. How can I do this?

Comment: Yo. Board is a tuple, that's how it's going to print. You could do `print(''.join(board))`.

Comment: Why did you make a tuple in the first place?

Comment: @user2357112 I'm new to programming and don't know what a tuple is. This just made sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't print whole tuple, but it's elements, e.g.:

```
for i in board:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use this line to print:

```
print(*board,sep="")
```

Explanation: the operator * is the unpacking operator: the tuple `board` is then unpacked, and it is like you've done:

```
print( places[8] + "|" + places[7] + "|" + places[6] + "\n",
       places[5] + "|" + places[4] + "|" + places[3] + "\n",
       places[2] + "|" + places[1] + "|" + places[0] + "\n",
       sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've put commas on the end of each line in the brackets, you've made a tuple, which is an iterable, like a list. Just replace the commas with a + at the start of the next line

```
board = ('line 1' + '\n'
         + 'line 2' + '\n'
         + 'line 3' + '\n')
```

This creates a string instead of a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

```
places = [" "] * 9

print(places[8] + "|" + places[7] + "|" + places[6] + "\n" + places[5] + "|" + 
places[4] + "|" + places[3] + "\n" + places[2] + "|" + places[1] + "|" + places[0] + 
"\n")
```

This is what you're looking for.

The problem was that "\n" only works *in* print statements.